# time difference in pandas with yesterday time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have a pandas Dataframe that includes the times in the following format:

```
2017-05-02  00:00:00+00:00
2017-05-03  01:00:00+00:00
```

I want to find their difference with a specific time in the previous day, say for the above example:

```
2017-05-01  10:00:00 
2017-05-02  10:00:00
```

I know that timedelta is the solution, but how I should use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html), substract one day and add 10 hours in `Timedelata`s to new `Series` dates which is substract from column `date`.

Advantage of solution is not necessary create helper column and then drop it.

```
print (df)
                        date
0  2017-05-02 00:00:00+00:00
1  2017-05-03 01:00:00+00:00

#if necessary convert to datetime
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
dates = df['date'].dt.floor('D') - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d') + pd.Timedelta(10, unit='h')
print (dates)
0   2017-05-01 10:00:00
1   2017-05-02 10:00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df['timedelta'] = df['date'] - dates
print (df)
                 date timedelta
0 2017-05-02 00:00:00  14:00:00
1 2017-05-03 01:00:00  15:00:00
```

For seconds from timedelata is possible use [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and another [solutions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion):

```
df['seconds'] = (df['date'] - dates).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print (df)
                 date  seconds
0 2017-05-02 00:00:00    50400
1 2017-05-03 01:00:00    54000
```

---

Same solution, only with new column is better if also need `new` column for another processing:

```
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['new'] = df['date'].dt.floor('D') - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d') + pd.Timedelta(10, unit='h')
print (df)
                 date                 new
0 2017-05-02 00:00:00 2017-05-01 10:00:00
1 2017-05-03 01:00:00 2017-05-02 10:00:00

df['seconds'] = (df['date'] - df['new']).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print (df)
                 date                 new  seconds
0 2017-05-02 00:00:00 2017-05-01 10:00:00    50400
1 2017-05-03 01:00:00 2017-05-02 10:00:00    54000
```